# Drupal 7 : View filtered with taxonomy / user relation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-nodes

I have a view "news" which is listing nodes from "news" content type.
This content type contains a field "countries" which is multiple.

So, my news "Test 1" will have a field countries like this one :
France, United Kingdom, Spain

My users have a field "Country".

What I want to do is to add a filter criteria in my view meaning :
News.countries = Users.country

At this moment, when I try to do it, I cannot set a "must be equal to" to News.countries, certainly because it is multiple.

Can you explain to me how should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a contextual filter. Add a relation to current logged in users country and add a contextual filter for the field new.country and use the relationship.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about relation or contextual filter. I tried to add the relation to the current logged in user, but it is not in the list.